# I have a query that returns '[ ]'. I want it to be shown on a widget as not having any value, how do I do this?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I have a query in my flutter app that should return empty if 'archived' 'isNull' is set to true. I accomplished that, but the issue I'm having now is the fact that the query returns empty (i.e [ ]). And on the widget, I want this to be shown as not having any value but instead, an empty pair of brackets '()' keep showing up.

I have tried checking for when query data equals null, something like this:

```
if (queryResult.data == null){
// The idea is for it not to just return '()' as the value
  value = null;
}
else{
value = queryResult.data;
}
```

And also:

```
if (queryResult.data == []){

  value = null;
}
else{
value = queryResult.data;
}
```

How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit the question and show definition of "value" and "data" variables.

Answer (score 0):

If "data" is a list why not try data.isEmpty() ? And also if you only need to avoid the brackets (dirty fix alert ⚠️)  whatever you did it's returning a string value '()' then you check that

> if(yourResults == '()' )value == null;

And please add more details for a better answer .